# Creating a session id based on a timestamp and an activity window (timeout)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a session_id for a dataset in redash based on an activity window. Essentially, I have a hit dataset, and I want to divide this into sessions where inactivity for an arbitrary length of time (I'm using 30 minutes, but could be anything) would indicate the end of a session (and the next hit would be the start of a new one).

I'm not a data expert (as the below will prove beyond doubt) - I've tried using lag and lead + case statements to identify the start and end of a session, but I want to be able to tag the rows through the middle as part of the session as well (I'd like to understand which users use the site the most, and which ones have the longest "journeys" on the site).

**an example dataset:**

| User_ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:29:00 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:39:00 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:59:00 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:19:00 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:25:00 |
| B2 | 2022-08-09 12:01:00 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:02:00 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:03:00 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:42:00 |

**What I'd like to get:**

| User_ID | Timestamp | Visit_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:29:00 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:39:00 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:59:00 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:19:00 | 2 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:25:00 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-09 12:01:00 | 1 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:02:00 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:03:00 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:42:00 | 3 |

**What I've got so far:**
identifying the start of each session:

```
SELECT 
a.user_id,
a.timestamp, 
case when timestamp - coalesce(lag(timestamp,1) over (partition by a.user_id order by timestamp),0) <= 1800 then 0
     else timestamp  
end as session_start
from example_dataset a
)
```

identifying the end of each session:

```
SELECT 
a.user_id,
a.timestamp, 
case when coalesce(lead(a.timestamp,1) over (partition by a.user_id order by a.timestamp),0) - a.timestamp <= 1800 then 0
     else a.timestamp  
end as session_end
from example_dataset a
)
```

What I don't know, is how to get from there to the nice neat dataset that I want. Can you help?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so no answers from anyone, I'm assuming that this means that I've not tagged it correctly or something. In the interests of helping some poor lost searcher in the future who has stumbled across this post, I've found a messy way around this.

Basically I'm:

1. Building the starts and ends as above
2. using a rank() over () function to essentially put an incremental visit_id on them
3. joining them together using the user_id and their ranks
4. joining that back onto the hit dataset using a messy time comparison
5. doing my analysis
6. having a glass of wine

Currently my issue is that the group_concat function that I was planning to use for pathing analysis doesn't seem to work..

Hopefully this helps, oh future internetanaut.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

1. Use lag() window function to find minute differences between consecutive timestamps. First row per user_id will result in null, so default them to -1.
2. Flag all minute differences resulting in -1 or greater than 30 minutes as 1, remaining as 0.
3. Use sum() window function on the previously calculated flags.

```
with cte as (
   select 'A1' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 21:29:00') time union all
   select 'A1' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 21:39:00') time union all
   select 'A1' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 21:59:00') time union all
   select 'A1' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 23:19:00') time union all
   select 'A1' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 23:25:00') time union all
   select 'B2' user_id, datetime('2022-08-09 12:01:00') time union all
   select 'B2' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 15:02:00') time union all
   select 'B2' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 15:03:00') time union all
   select 'B2' user_id, datetime('2022-08-10 15:42:00') time
)
SELECT
    *,
    sum(case when min_diff = -1 or min_diff > 30 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by time) as visit_id
from (
  select
      *,
      coalesce((strftime('%s', time) - strftime('%s', lag(time) over (partition by user_id order by time)))/60, -1) min_diff
  from cte
)
```

Resulting in:

| user_id | time | min_diff | visit_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:29:00 | -1 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:39:00 | 10 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 21:59:00 | 20 | 1 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:19:00 | 80 | 2 |
| A1 | 2022-08-10 23:25:00 | 6 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-09 12:01:00 | -1 | 1 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:02:00 | 1621 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:03:00 | 1 | 2 |
| B2 | 2022-08-10 15:42:00 | 39 | 3 |